# Java/Android MainActivity Syntax Confusing - Need some Clarification

Tags: java, android, mobile, syntax, sdk

I'm new to Java and Android development as a whole so I'm sure this question pertains to a gap in knowledge in my part on how Java actually works so I'm hoping someone can help me fill this gap. I've been coding in Python, Javascript, and other OOP languages for a couple years but I'm finding Java/Android Dev to break some of the conventions I've come to know and understand.

Below is a very basic class definition for a MainActivity, I believe it's a part of the standard Android tutorials

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

}
```

Overall this code makes perfect sense to me. A class is defined called MainActivity that inherits the AppCompatActivity class and overrides the onCreate method. The instance state is saved, a layout is initialized and then a textView is initialized.

The area of my confusion comes from the textView initialization.

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

The space between (TextView) and the findViewById method baffles me. Why is this allowed? Shouldn't it be something more like,

```
textView = (TextView).findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Again I'm completely new to Java and still learning the syntax and language constructs but this seems a little strange to me. How can a method be called like this? Thanks again in advance. I've been having a little trouble wording this question for a google search.

Answer (score 0):

Defining this programmatically sentence is standard android java coding

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

either you can go for

```
textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

For more information please refer [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int))

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score -2):

(TextView) only casts the object found by `findViewbyId`. 
`R.layout.test` should contain a `TextView` with id `textView`.

Comment: I see I didn't fully understand object casting. Thanks for answering